# Having some issues with missing fonts

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, fonts, typography

I have several InDesign/Illustrator files to edit and I am repeatedly getting a missing fonts issue. I'll have the fonts on my computer but they will be named slightly differently than what InDesign or Illustrator is saying I am missing. For example, InDesign will say I'm missing "DIN Bold" but I'll have the font and it will be named DINOT Bold on my computer. Is it as simple as changing the name of my system font to correct this issue or does it go deeper? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many typefaces come in different variations, some may not be noticeably different at all. A lot of typefaces are released by a number of different foundries. The font may even just be in a different format with different naming. So the font you have may be a different variation of the same typeface, or it may even be the same typeface from a different source with only a variation in the naming. In either case it is a different *font**.

Theres not much you can do about it. Either replace the font with your version (go to **Type → Find Font...**) or find out which exact font is used.

* See: [What is the difference between a font and a typeface?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12717/what-is-the-difference-between-a-font-and-a-typeface)